# Is there another meaning behind the words "Urim Vetumim"?

Tags: sources-mekorot, hebrew, college-university-school

We all know the classical meaning of the words אורים ותומים (loosely translated: light and truth), referring to the Choshen Mishpat, I was wondering if there is another accepted meaning of the words when I noticed that the Yale university logo has the Hebrew letters "אורים ותומים" on it, 
You can see the logo clearly [on the Wikimedia image](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%91%D7%A5:Official_Yale_Shield.png).

Comment: Probably because they thought it's cool. If I know my Latin (which I don't), I think it's the translation of their motto "Lux et Veritas," on the banner under the shield. Google Translate [verified](https://translate.google.com/#la/en/lux%20et%20veritas).

Comment: @Shokhet I think its cool too, because i am Jewish! I was asking because I think that there was probably a better reason. Especially since they were known to be anti Semitic back then (like most university's)

Comment: Fair enough. Let's see what turns up.

Comment: ...maybe their founders knew where the Urim v'Tummim are hidden?!?  Wow!  I was just guessing---http://westvilleshul.org/content/urim-vtumim-history-yales-insignia-and-jewish-thought-today

Comment: @Gary Nice find! That pretty much answers the question.

Comment: @Shokhet - as I was reading through it I realized that it indeed contained the answer...but it was closed as I was summarizing it, oh well... If anyone else is curious - in a nutshell, it was a term they decided to appropriate and use for the Founder of Christianity.

Comment: @Gary Thanks I checked out the link, its a great answer, hopefully now that i edited the question, the hold will be taken off